# What is the best way to write inner join query in SQL?

Tags: sql

First Way:

```
SELECT  ST.PersonID, ST.CustomerID, ST.SaleTypeID, ST.PaymentGatewayID, 
                    ST.CustomerMembershipID, ST.CustomerPaymentGatewayID, P.Currency
            FROM ServiceTransaction ST
            INNER JOIN dbo.Person P ON ST.PersonID = P.PersonID;
```

Second Way:

```
 SELECT  ST.PersonID, ST.CustomerID, ST.SaleTypeID, ST.PaymentGatewayID, 
                    ST.CustomerMembershipID, ST.CustomerPaymentGatewayID, P.Currency
            FROM ServiceTransaction ST
            INNER JOIN dbo.Person P ON P.PersonID = ST.PersonID;
```

I want to optimize this query in SQL. Currently I am using second way and I need expert opinion, which one is best approach.
However, any one can add some new way to optimize this query as well.

Comment: Makes no difference, purely personal preference

Comment: It doesn't matter, the optimizer will find the best way.

Comment: The two queries are word-for-word identical.

Answer (score -1):

As comments suggest, they are identical in many aspects. For a personal note tho if you keep the same format it gets easier to follow so I use the following schema to keep tabs on tables where I always use lower numbered table on left side

SELECT Column_list
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2
INNER JOIN TABLE3
ON Table1.ColName = Table2.ColName
ON Table1.ColName = Table3.ColName | ON Table2.ColName = Table3.ColName

This way when you are working with multiple tables and joins it is easier to follow which table is joined where and which table was mentioned first in the query.

Comment: The "lower numbered table"? Is this a joke? You are not really calling your tables table1, table2, etc., are you? Tables should be called according to what they contain, say `products`, `employees`, whatever. And you should write the queries such that the order makes sense, e.g. select from the orders table, join the order details (one row per order and product) and then the products. Only then can you easily apply chains of left outer joins where needed.

Comment: as in 1st table, 2nd table not really numbered but first used, 2nd used etc. so if I'm selecting from products and left joining employees, products would be my 1st table and I'd use it on the left side of = operations. Doesn't have to be like that but I find it easier to track which table I've used first and which is joined on which order